# Remote desktop thru firewall via vpn

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn

Scheme:

```
My_macbook -> INTERNET -> Linux_Proxy_Firewall-> Lion_On_The_Internal_Network
```

So, need set up encrypted tunnel between my macbook and Linux firewall and want connect into the internal Lion via Apple Remote Desktop.

Looking for a simple, bulletproof - verified solution (so, from someone who really use it) for using ARD via VPN (road warrior config).

Probably here is a way setup tunnels with plain ssh(1) or with [SshTunnelManager](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/stm/), but never tried it yet - so any advice and/or real experiences is welcomed...

Asking for **real experience** because [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1882) Apple wrote:

> When using VPN, you may need to set your router to allow a larger MTU
>   and/or to disallow fragmented packets. For details, refer to the Admin
>   Guide for your version of Apple Remote Desktop.

Comment: Are you already running VPN software on your Linux firewall?

Comment: no, but isn't problem install "it". I'm currently using only ssh(1) tunnels for mail and for access the internal web-server. As I wrote, i never tried any ARD/VPN setup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... simple with ssh-tunnels:

Into the terminal:

```
ssh -N -p 22 -c 3des user@firewall.example.com -L 15900/10.1.1.1/5900 -L 13283/10.1.1.1/3283
```

Where:

```
user@firewall.example.com - is an valid username on the firewall, and
10.1.1.1 - is the address of the lion-server on the internal network
```

This will create two tunnels between local computer and remote firewall.
In the Remote Desktop.app you should manually add the remote server like this:

[image: ARD config]

Now, you can observe/control the "internal-server" via tunnels thru firewall.example.com.